# Unable to run the gradle run command

Tags: java, gradle, build-automation

Here is my directory structure

[image: Here is the directory structure]

Here is my build.gradle file

[image]

When I try to run the Gradle command ... `grade run --info` I'm getting the following error

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location of the compiled class:

```
build/classes/java/main/SampleFile.class
```

does not match the location of the java file:

```
src/in/swapnilsingh/SampleFile.java
```

The `in/swapnilsingh` package directories are missing.

You are probably missing the package declaration at the top of the java file:

```
package in.swapnilsingh;

public class SampleFile {
    // ...
}
```

Without the package declaration, the compiler will output the class file to the root of the output directory, the default package.

You can either add the package to the top of the `SampleFile.java` file or remove the package prefix from the `mainClassName` in the `build.gradle`:

```
mainClassName = 'SampleFile'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've forgotten to add the package declaration on the top of my java file. Now everything is working just fine.